# How to order by nulls-last by a linked table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, stuff

I have two tables **Person** and **PersonSkill**

**Person**

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Person 1 |
| 2 | Person 2 |
| 3 | Person 3 |

**PersonSkill**

| PERSON_ID | SKILL | SORT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sing | 20 |
| 1 | Playful | 10 |
| 2 | Sing | 10 |
| 1 | Bowl | 30 |
| 1 | SQL | 40 |

I'm trying to write a order by which will sort the persons by skills alphabetically but nulls last.

Looking for something like this:

```
SELECT distinct
  p.*,
  STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + ps.SKILL
      FROM PersonSkill ps
      WHERE ps.PERSON_ID = p.ID
      ORDER BY ps.SORT
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') sortRule
FROM Person p
ORDER BY IIF(sortRule is null, 1, 0) asc, sortRule asc
```

But for some reason I can't use sortRule inside an `IIF` or a `case` operation within ORDER BY as it's giving me this error: `Invalid column name 'sortRule'.`

If I remove the `STUFF` `sortRule` from the select statement it will tell me that it is required to be there when using alongside `distinct`. I also can't just copy the `STUFF` down to the order by as it will say: `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.`

Comment: You've tagged [[tag:stuff]] here, but `STUFF` has very little to do with the logic in the above. All it's going is removing the first character, which is a comma (`,`), from a string. it's `FOR XML PATH` that is doing the "magic" (playing the role of `STRING_AGG`).

Comment: What is the relevance of using XML PATH here? Does your input have xml data?

Comment: I literally tell you in my comment above, @manibharataraju ... *"it's `FOR XML PATH` that is doing the "magic" (playing the role of `STRING_AGG`)."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're performing string aggregation, then you should be using a `GROUP BY`, not `DISTINCT`. As for sorting on `sortRule`, you can't wrap a column's alias in an expression in the `ORDER BY`. One method, therefore, is to use a CTE:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT p.Id,
           p.[Name],
           STUFF((SELECT ',' + ps.SKILL
                  FROM dbo.PersonSkill ps
                  WHERE ps.PERSON_ID = p.ID
                  ORDER BY ps.SORT
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS sortRule
    FROM dbo.Person p
    GROUP BY p.Id,
             p.[Name])
SELECT *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CASE WHEN sortRule IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         sortRule;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2464605e9009a2becaf7065e4f61a6ec)